# Create firebird data source in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, firebird, sql-server-ce

I have an app in c# using Visual Studio 2010 express and realized the sqlce database i was using does not meet all of our needs.

I am trying to figure out how to add a firebird datasource and point to my firebird database.  I want to mimic the sqlce dataset creating a new dataset but with designer.   I think my first step needs to be getting the data source added but I can't figure out how to do it.  Any ideas?

I tried following this article:
http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_adonet/p2_visual_studio_2008.html#server_explorer
as well as additional links within this article but have not had luck.  I tried installing the ibprovider professional suite and it looks like it insalled as i see it in program files but I am not certain what it is doing exactly.  I also installed a odbc provider from the easysoft.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is related I will ask this here.  I can see the provider, enter all information but when i attempt to test the connection i am getting:Access is Denied

Comment: Are you using "SYSDBA" with password "masterkey"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this.  I do remember making changes to the machine.config.  Look at these, these instructions sound familiar. http://www.basarat.com/2010/02/setting-up-firebird-development-with-vs.html http://www.basarat.com/2010/05/setting-up-portable-firebird-full-with.html

edit:
I just installed it, this is what I did:

- I downloaded the latest
  FireBirdClient.msi and DDEX provider
  from [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider).
- Installed the .msi and extracted the
  DDEX zip.
- Used the Visual Studio Command prompt
  and navigated to C:\Program Files
  (x86)\FirebirdClient.
- Did gacutil /i
  FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient FYI, **after the .dll doesn't show up in the gac for some reason**
- Then, gacutil /l
  FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient and left it open so I could copy the Version and PublicKeyToken later.
- I modified my machine.config in
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
  **AND** C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
  and followd these instructions.

**Note: %RuntimeVersion% vs. %Version%**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
    <section name="firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=%RuntimeVersion%, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    ...
  <configSections>
...
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      ...
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=%Version%, Culture=%Culture%, PublicKeyToken=%PublicKeyToken%" />
      ...
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>

And substitute (these informations you can find using gacutil):
  - %RuntimeVersion% with either 2.0.0.0 (.NET 2.0, .NET 3.0, .NET 3.5) or 4.0.0.0 (.NET 4). 
  - %Version% with the version of the provider assembly that you have in the GAC.
  - %Culture% with the culture of the provider assembly that you have in the GAC.
  - %PublicKeyToken% with the PublicKeyToken of the provider assembly that you have in the GAC.
```

- From the DDEX extract I copyied the
  two .dll's
  FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll
  and
  FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataToolsUI.dll
  to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.
- The last thing I did was modify the 2
  registry files from the DDEX extract
  changing the path for each to
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  Visual Studio
  10.0\Common7\I\DE\FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll
  and merged them.

edit: adding [this](http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/Using_Firebird_within_Visual_Studio) as a reference noted by bline22 in the comments.

Comment: any idea how to get the firbirdsql.data.firebirdclient.dll into to the gac.  when i tried using gacutil i got an error that it was using the wrong run time so i went to the netfx4.0 folder and used the gacutil there but it drops it into the windows/microsoft.net/assembly folder instead of the windows/assembly folder

Comment: I can look at it when I get home.

Comment: Maybe it is OK where it is I am not sure.  But I am trying to get the public token and that info from it.  when i use the sn -t tool it says the assembly doesn't exist but I see it under the windows/microsoft.net/assmebly/GAC_MISL/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient folder

Comment: Derek, thanks again for the response.  I don't know if you were able to look at what I was saying above.  Want to make sure I am not overlooking something and that this is in fact an issue in integrating firebird with Visual studio.  i hope not and simply due to my lack of knowledge.  If anyone else has had this and was able to fix it I would love to hear form you.  Thanks again.

Comment: I used gacutil /i to install it into the cache.

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  leaving the .dll off did reveal it so that is good.  I came across something last night while searching that i think stated there might be issues running this on Visual Studio express which is what I am running.  Are you running express?

Comment: Oh yeah, the Readme.txt says the DDEX provider didn't work with express.  I'm using pro.

Comment: That is where I saw it.  Dang.  I am going to go and buy it later this week and try it again.  I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Derek, thanks again for the help and i can now at least see it.  Took a lot of tinkering.  Also, this site is a good reference.  one thing that took me the longest with this was that I did not use // in the registry file.  Thanks again:   http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/Using_Firebird_within_Visual_Studio