# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise - Installing Firebird as ADO Entity Data Source

Tags: visual-studio, firebird

With much struggle, I was able to get the Firebird ADO.NET Entity Data Source Driver installed on my Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.  It took a while to get it all worked out, but I manage by following the tutorials located here

[Create firebird data source in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446580/create-firebird-data-source-in-visual-studio)

http://onlineservicetools.com/en_US/how-to-install-ddex-firebird-provider-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2017/

However, I've just purchased VS 2017 Enterprise and installed it, and uninstalled my VS2017 Community Edition.  Now the Firebird Database no longer shows up as an option for me to choose from when I create a new Model in my MVC application.

I've gone through the steps again, however it's not working.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can try?

Comment: I suggest you ask on the firebird-net-provider Google Group / mailing list. I'm not sure if based on the information provided we can give you an answer here, and I'm unsure what clarifications to ask for.

Comment: https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233604-installing-ddex-provider-for-firebird-into-visual-studio-2017